# Dynamically add item to StackLayout

Tags: qt, dynamic, qml, stacklayout

I have create an item in a file called NetworkSheet.  My other QML file (A.qml) contains a StackLayout (id tabStack) and I would like to add NetworkSheet onto the back of the stack.

I'm going in circles due to a couple of incomplete examples.  Can someone suggest how to do this?  THe closest I got is:

```
var stackItem = Qt.createQmlObject('import "../tabs"; NetworkSheet{}', tabStack);
tabStack.children.push(stackItem);
```

but there is no push method for tabStack's children.

Comment: Would a `StackView` work in your app rather than a `StackLayout`? StackView has easy push/pop methods built-in.

Comment: I am using a TabBar to control my StackLayout (to simulate switching pages when user clicks a tab).  Can StackView work with this?  (I don't see a writeable currentIndex property so not sure it can work)

Comment: A TabBar **can** work with a StackView, but it won't be quite as simple since there is no currentIndex property. One way to do it is each TabButton could have an onClicked handler to push whatever page you want to show.

Comment: Interestingly if I just used the first line of code above (remove second line) and it seems to append the object onto the stack and show properly!  (Just experimenting).  Is there anything wrong with doing that?

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong with it at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to append/insert the newly created Item onto the StackLayout.  By specifying the parent (as the StackLayout) during creation it automatically gets appended onto the end.  So just this line is needed:

```
var stackItem = Qt.createQmlObject('import "../tabs"; NetworkSheet{}', tabStack);
```